# Accessing "real_field_non_translated"? - Mobility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

Is there a way, via ActiveRecord, to access the "real_field" (let's say)?

For example. If I have a Model Company and do `Company.create(name: "My Company Name")` (with `I18n.locale = :en`), that name value won't be saved in the Company record, but in the Mobility table for the string.

So doing `Company.last` will return

`#<Company id: 5, name: nil>`

But doing `Company.last.name` will return My Company Name (assuming the locale is set properly)

Is there a way to do something like `Company.last.real_name` that would give me the actual value of the record? In this case nil. I would also like to have a `real_name=`.

> mobility (0.4.2)
>         i18n (>= 0.6.10, < 0.10)
>         request_store (~> 1.0)
>
> Backend: key_value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Company.last.read_attribute :name
```

Or this:

```
Company.last.name_before_type_cast
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks. Also, if someone comes looking for the same thing, using `write_attribute` and then `.save` will save the field

Comment: You can also use the shorthand `company[:name]` instead of `company.read_attribute :name`, or `company[:name] = ...` instead of `company.write_attribute :name, ...`.

Comment: You can also pass the `super` option to Mobility, which would normally do the same thing: `company.name(super: true)`.

Comment: Nice points @ChrisSalzberg! They would even deserve another answer IMHO; specially the last one, which seems the most idiomatic using Mobility

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct as a general approach with any ActiveRecord model: `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` will always fetch and set the column value regardless of any overrides defined in the model. As I commented, there are shorthandes for these methods as well:

```
company[:name]         #=> returns the value of the name column
company[:name] = "foo" #=> sets the value of the name column to "foo"
```

In addition, in Mobility specifically, there is an option you can pass to a getter (and setter) which will skip whatever *Mobility* would normally do for an attribute:

```
company.name(super: true) # skips Mobility and goes to its parent (super) method,
                          # which would typically be the column value.
```

In a situation where perhaps you are using another gem which also does something special to attributes, this approach might work better.

There is also a setter option, however it's a bit more tricky to use:

```
company.send(:name=, "foo", super: true) # sets name to "foo", skipping Mobility
```

If you are using Mobility together with another gem that overrides attribute getters and/or setters, then the `super` option may be useful; otherwise read/write attribute is probably fine.